# php with oracle client 11g

Tags: php, iis, oracle11g, client

We have both `.net` and `php` running on `iis`. We have `oracle client11g` (not `instaclient`) installed.

While accessing `oracle` database from `.net` there is no problem. But in case of accessing `oracle` from `php` it looks for `instaclient`.

How to access `oracle` from `php` with normal client?

Comment: Please share your code which you are facing problem with.Thanks

Comment: There does not seem to be much documentation on "how to". You might have to dig into the source code of oci8.